# No org-babel execute function for go

Tags: org-mode, init-file, org-babel, literate-programming

```
#+Begin_SRC go
package main
import ("fmt")

func main(){
   fmt.Println("emacs")
}
#+End_Src
```

`~/.emacs.d/init.el`:

```
(when (memq window-system '(mac ns))
  (exec-path-from-shell-initialize)
  (exec-path-from-shell-copy-env "GOPATH"))

;; Define function to call when go-mode loads
(defun my-go-mode-hook ()
  (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'gofmt-before-save) ; gofmt before every save
  (setq gofmt-command "goimports")                ; gofmt uses invokes goimports
  (if (not (string-match "go" compile-command))   ; set compile command default
      (set (make-local-variable 'compile-command)
           "go build -v && go test -v && go vet"))

  ;; guru settings
  (go-guru-hl-identifier-mode)                    ; highlight identifiers

  ;; Key bindings specific to go-mode
  (local-set-key (kbd "M-.") 'godef-jump)         ; Go to definition
  (local-set-key (kbd "M-*") 'pop-tag-mark)       ; Return from whence you came
  (local-set-key (kbd "M-p") 'compile)            ; Invoke compiler
  (local-set-key (kbd "M-P") 'recompile)          ; Redo most recent compile cmd
  (local-set-key (kbd "M-]") 'next-error)         ; Go to next error (or msg)
  (local-set-key (kbd "M-[") 'previous-error)     ; Go to previous error or msg


  (auto-complete-mode 1))                         


(add-hook 'go-mode-hook 'my-go-mode-hook)

(with-eval-after-load 'go-mode
   (require 'go-autocomplete))

(require 'go-guru)
; i want use ob-go , above code just compile the code
;(require 'ob-go)
;(org-babel-do-load-languages
;'org-babel-load-languages
;'((go . t)))
```

But this is not execute how i execute this block. I'm new in Literal Programming Please help me

Comment: Why do you have the code to add `go` to languages supported by org-babel commented out?

Comment: because i like go and project requirements in c,c++,go,lisp,clojure and ruby. Second i used go for most of problems

Comment: That code should register a function which should handle go blocks in org-mode, possibly including code block execution. That's probably your issue.

Comment: by adding org-mode ?

Comment: The 4 last lines of your init file have code that should add go support to `org-babel`, but you've commented them out.

Answer (score 5):

You already have necessary code to enable go support for `org-babel` in your init file, it's just commented out. All it takes to enable it is to uncomment them.

Change the following part (which is right at the end of your init file):

```
; i want use ob-go , above code just compile the code
;(require 'ob-go)
;(org-babel-do-load-languages
;'org-babel-load-languages
;'((go . t)))
```

You just have to remove heading semicolons at the beginning of last 4 lines, (which is the syntax for comments) which should leave you with something looking like this:

```
; i want use ob-go , above code just compile the code
(require 'ob-go)
(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages
 '((go . t)))
```